# Filtering laravel collection with eloquent relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about filtering in Laravel collection.

Here is the case:
I have Test model where I have eloquent relation hasMany with Question model. In my index method in TestController I want to take only tests that have 3 or more questions.

```
$tests = Test::where(function($test) {
    return $test->questions->count() > 3;
})->get();
```

Something like code below, but obviously that wont work.

Thank in advance.

PS: This is my first question in stackoverflow, sorry for bad English...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$tests = Test::has('questions', '>=', 3)->get();
```

for more info read [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)